# Setting up Hotmail IMAP in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap, hotmail

So I've been trying to get hotmail setup in Thunderbird but I cannot get it to work. I know hotmail IMAP works fine in Windows Live Mail. How can I get it to work in Thunderbird?

Comment: AFAIK, Hotmail only has POP3 support, and not IMAP.

Comment: You think IMAP is working in `WindowsLiveMail`, but this is not true: It is a proprietary protocol (only available to MS). So sad but true.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Thunderbird FAQ](http://www.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/faq):

> **Can I access my Yahoo!, Hotmail, Lycos (Europe), MailDotCom, Gmail, and Libero WebMail account through Thunderbird?**
>
> Yes. The Webmail extension integrates web site based email accounts into Thunderbird, allowing Thunderbird to download and to send emails using the web site. Some services may require a subscription for this type of access. Current information on the Webmail extension, supported services, and other add-ons for web based email can be found at the [WebMail](http://webmail.mozdev.org/) development site.

So you can do it, but not through IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Webmail extension](http://webmail.mozdev.org/) for Firefox.

See also [Using webmail with your email client](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_webmail_with_your_email_client).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: [How to Access Free Windows Live Hotmail in Mozilla Thunderbird](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/et_free_hotmail.htm)

Scroll to mid-page - **Access Free Windows Live Hotmail in Mozilla Thunderbird Using IzyMail**

Comment: **IzyMail is Not Free**
`IzyMail provides great access to free Windows Live Hotmail accounts, but it is not itself free. You can try the service for free, though.` (cited from http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/et_izymail.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime it is possible [without the plugin](https://superuser.com/questions/129850/is-there-a-way-to-read-hotmail-mail-with-thunderbird-without-using-the-webmail-pl)!

Comment: But only with POP3 - not IMAP as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using IMAP if you go via Gmail... sounds like a long way around but if you get Gmail to POP in your emails from your Hotmail mailbox (set up a Gmail account, go to settings, accounts and import...) then you can synchronize Gmail with Thunderbird using IMAP.

It works really well but depends if you like the Gmail interface... though you can always just use Thunderbird.

There's more detail on this in a free guide you can get at www.Easy-Email.net.
cheers,
Kerry

Comment: This answer is not really helpful, as gmail is NOT reading the folders from Hotmail.