# Is there a way to read Hotmail mail with Thunderbird without using the WebMail pluging?

Tags: thunderbird, email, hotmail, pop3, windows-live-messenger

Some sites tell me Hotmail has POP3 access now, but with Thunderbird it doesn't seem to work. The only solution (which I didn't test yet) is a WebMail plugin that helps Thunderbird to read data from MSN Live / Hotmail.
Did anyone get this to work?

Comment: I'm still having problems synchronizing the folders: see http://superuser.com/questions/132232/can-i-synchronize-hotmail-folders-in-thunderbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Thunderbird+and+Hotmail

Comment: It helps if you quote the relevant part of the page you're linking to. If the quote would be too long then a summary would do.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my password was too long. That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Roland Tangloa :

In here: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Thunderbird-and-Hotmail

The IMAP settings are:

```
Server Name: imap-mail.outlook.com
Port: 993
User Name: your username (for example j.kowal@outlook.com)
Connection security: SSL/TLS
Authentication method: Normal password
```