# Can I synchronize hotmail folders in thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, pop3, windows-live-messenger, hotmail

I'm using Thunderbird to load my Hotmail mail. It works fine (see [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/129850/is-there-a-way-to-read-hotmail-mail-with-thunderbird-without-using-the-webmail-pl)).

But there is one problem: How can I synchronize the folders I've defined online in Hotmail?
And is it possible to archive these mails again in the existing folders?

Comment: I'd suggest switching from HotMail to GMail first - GMail supports full syncrhonization via IMAP.  I'm guessing HotMail does too, but GMail is better

Answer (score 2):

http://webmail.mozdev.org/setup.html is the site that has a plugin for thunderbird to synchronize the folders, which works most of the time until Microsoft changes the interface of the folders again :) Then you must wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail currently supports POP3 (download of email messages) but not IMAP (which will allow you to synchronize your folders on hotmail and in Thunderbird).

Since you don't want to use the webmail plugin for thunderbird, then I would recommend switching to GMail, you can have full IMAP access to your folders and perform the synchronization in an easier way.

- You can continue to use your @hotmail.com address if you want, the only thing you need to setup is forwarding all your hotmail email to @gmail.com
- An "identity" can be configured under your gmail account to sent mail from your @hotmail.com address.
- In GMail you can create the "folders" (actually in GMail they are called labels) and use them to organize your email and also synchronize them to folders in Thunderbird.
- This solution would be more stable over time since it uses the IMAP standard features and will not break when Hotmail makes changes to the interface.

Comment: -1 The OP was asking about Hotmail, not Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Removing prenumerations will fix it.

1. File → Prenumerations... → mail@hotmail.com for all Hotmail folders
2. Click OK
3. Re-enable them

The folders then showed up.

I used the automatic setup for IMAP through Thunderbird, so hopefully there aren't more variables to it.